# Cordova relative path fails because content is under android_assets/www

Tags: android, cordova

I have CSS files that use a relative path e.g. font-awesome references '/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff'. However this fails when run under android because the files are reference under 'file:///android_assets/www/'.

Is there are way to config cordova to use "file:///android_assets/www/" as the root path when "/somepath.img" which currently resolves as "file:///somepath.img". In a browser I could do  however this does not work here. If not I will need to update all reference in CSS to be relative to the current folder.

Comment: All relative paths are always relative to the current folder. So i do not understand your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I left out a backslash. "/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff" is still a relative path but relative to the root. An absolute path would be something like "file://android_assets/www/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff".

Comment: if you are referencing "manually" to ` 'file://android_assets/www/'.` the path is wrong. Try --> `file:///android_asset/www/..... ` look that file have 3 slashes

Comment: @Shudy, sorry I just typed that instead of pasting and left out the extra /. That part works fine, I am just looking for a way to avoid updating all references in CSS files. e.g. something like <base href="file:///android_assets/www/" />

Comment: @ChrisHerring OK, then I can't help anymore :( Cordoba is not my friend.. ^^. Hope you find the solution